# "Answer to my question" or "answer on my question"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

What's the right usage: an answer *to* my question or *on* my question?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"To" is right; "on" would be intelligible, but not the usual way to say it: it would mean "an answer on the subject of my question", which is needlessly long and less clear, except perhaps in unusual contexts. You would use "on" in sentences where you could use "about" with the same meaning: "I read his answer on food processing, and it was rather interesting". "Food processing" is the general subject of the answer, and so probably of the question as well – it is not the question itself.

Comment: Is `One of the principles was to reward the dog every time he answered to his name.` correct?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade: Yes, why? What were you uncertain about?

Comment: Thanks @Cerberus! I thought `... answered his name.` was correct (for I thought this was similar to `Why don't you answer your phone?`)

Comment: @KedarMhaswade: You can answer the source of the external utterance (another person, a phone), but you answer *to* whatever the external utterance *is* (a word or words used in the utterance, or the form or format of the utterance): *I answered her, I answered the phone, I answered to his call, I answered to my name*. The reason is that answering an utterance—without *to* —indicates that *you* are the source of the utterance: *I answered my name* = I said my name (although this construction is probably rare except with a *that...* clause).